# Need some information regarding deploying react app with node js backend with phpmyadmin mysql database

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, heroku, cpanel

I want to publish this website online which requires hosting and server for deploying everything react app, node js, mysql database, I want to know which site is preferred for everything at one place WHat I mostly found is:

1- cPanel works with react app but node js backend im not sure i cant find anything online its mixed reviews.

2- Heroku offers $5 eco monthly subscription but i couldn't find details for deploying react app and node js backend together with phpmyadmin including in this $5 subscription.

which would be the cheapest solution ? if its heroku then is 1000 dyno hours enough monthly ? and will it supports reactapp + nodejs + mysql ? or I have to deploy React app somewhere else and nodejs to heroku ? All opinions are appreciated Thanks.

**NOT:** React app is website, node js is only for backend calls, mysql is for database, dont confuse node js with frontend and backend.

Comment: react is just a frontend framework. There should be no problems communicating with a node backend or a sql database. I usually pipe requests through node (express) from my react app to communicate with databases. Cheapest solution has a lot of questions about what your app is / what kind of usage it will see.

Comment: thanks, my node is also express, my app is admin panel its mostly store and preview user data and sends sms emails etc thats all, my main issue is deploying 3 parts (react app, nodejs, mysql database) together at heroku does it covers in $5 ?